# What type of object is returned from ObjectForID

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to retrieve an object from the managed object context and edit a value or two after it has been backed up to the cloud.  In particular, I want to save an id provided by the cloud server.

To get the object, I'm trying to retrieve it using its managedObjectID.

I have tried:

```
 Contacts *object = [_managedObjectContext objectWithID:_moID];
```

and

```
Contacts *object = [self.managedObjectContext objectRegisteredForID:_moID];
```

where moID is the managedObject id.

I then follow this up with

```
object.cid = @99; //ie I set it equal to some number
```

In both cases, although Contacts is an NSManagedObject class, it throws a yellow warning:

> 'Incompatible point types initializing contacts with an expression of type NSManagedObject'.

If Instead of calling it `Contacts *object`, I call it `NSManagedObject *object`, it no longer throws the warning but then will not allow me to say `object.cid` as it no longer knows what a cid is.  In this case it throws red error:

> Property cid not found on object of type NSManagedObject.

Can anyone suggest proper object type.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the method definition, you'll see that returned instance type is just `NSManagedObject *` as the warning said. What you need to do is just to cast the type appropriately:

```
Contacts *object = (Contacts *)[_managedObjectContext objectWithID:_moID];
```

and

```
Contacts *object = (Contacts *)[self.managedObjectContext objectRegisteredForID:_moID];
```

Note, your `Contacts` suppose to be a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.